quarkus multiple logging filters
The quarkus application property quarkus.log.console.filter seems to support only one filter. For example,
quarkus.log.console.filter=myfilter

will work fine provided that a class like
@io.quarkus.logging.LoggingFilter(name = "myfilter")
public class LoggingFilter implements Filter {
    //...
}

exists.
If however more than one filter is specified
quarkus.log.console.filter=myfilter,yourfilter

When the app starts up, in the console there is the following message:
LogManager error of type GENERIC_FAILURE: Unable to find named filter 'myfilter,yourfilter'

It seems only one filter is admissible here: are there any known workarounds?

It is not possible at the time of writing to specify more than one logging filter in quarkus. As a workaround, since all logging filters implement the Filter interface, they can be combined:
@io.quarkus.logging.LoggingFilter(name = "multiple-filter")
public class MultipleFilter implements Filter {

    private final Filter filter1;

    private final Filter filter2;

    public MultipleFilter(Filter1 filter1, Filter2 filter2) {
        this.filter1 = filter1;
        this.filter2 = filter2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
        return filter1.isLoggable(record) && filter2.isLoggable(record);
    }
}

